# Specifying the full path to an entity with inheritance hierarchies in contains_eager()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query like

```
(session.query(Root).with_polymorphic('*')
    .outerjoin(Subclass.related1).options(contains_eager(Subclass.related1)))
```

So far things work.

I want also want to eagerly load `Related1.related2` and I tried this:

```
(session.query(Root).with_polymorphic('*')
    .outerjoin(Subclass.related1).options(contains_eager(Subclass.related1))
    .outerjoin(Related1.related2).options(contains_eager(Related1.related2)))
```

But it doesn't work:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't find property 'related2' on any entity specified in this Query.  Note the full path from root (Mapper|Root|root) to target entity must be specified.

Given that `related1` is related to the root entity via a subclass I don't see how to specify the full path.

I also tried

```
(session.query(Root).with_polymorphic('*')
    .outerjoin(Subclass.related1).options(contains_eager(Subclass.related1))
    .outerjoin(Related1.related2).options(contains_eager('related1.related2')))
```

which predictably fails with

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't find property named 'related1' on the mapped entity Mapper|Root|root in this Query.

How can I specify the full path to the indirectly-related entity in `contains_eager()`?

Comment: This helped us. We had single table inheritance and and join table inheritance. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance_loading.html#polymorphic-selectin-loading

Answer (score 24, accepted):

contains_eager needs a full path from the entities the query knows about:

```
contains_eager(Subclass.related1, Related1.related2)
```

Comment: After almost ten years your answer has helped me solve problem with async sqlalchemy session ;)